# Problemas con importación de DBF con paquetes foreign y spsurvey en R

Tags: r, importación

Esta es la parte de mi código que cree ayer para iterar un script que había preparado con un path específico. Ayer el código corría con el paquete foreign. Hoy que agregué la parte iterativa ya no funciona. También intenté con spsurvey pero es lo mismo. Me pregunto si el problema son los argumentos que utilicé con las funciones para iterar o con la ruta. Saludos

```
  setwd("C:/Users/.../Documents/Datos/Scince/Estados/")

  files <- list.files(path ="C:/Users/.../Documents/Datos/Scince/Estados/", 
               full.names = T, recursive = F)

for(i in 1:length(files)){
lapply(files, function(x){          

      #require(spsurvey)

      require (foreign)

      pob <- read.dbf("files[i]/ageb_urb.dbf")

Error in read.dbf("files[i]/ageb_urb.dbf") : unable to open DBF file
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido al [es.SO]. Como tal aquí sólo tratamos las preguntas realizadas en Español. Deberías traducir la pregunta.

Comment: Gracias @JuankGlezz . Traducción: Esta es la parte de mi código que cree ayer para iterar un script que había preparado con un path específico. Ayer el código corria con el paquete foreign. Hoy que agregué la parte iterativa ya no funciona. También intenté con spsurvey pero es lo mismo. Me pregunto si el problema son los argumentos que utilicé con las funciones para iterar o con la ruta. Saludos

Comment: Volvere a postear la pregunta en español

Comment: @RubénFernández Hola, tienes que estudiar tu código, pues `for` y `lappy` hacen cosas similares por lo que creo que no estás muy seguro de lo que haces. El problema no es el leer el archivo DBF sino como iterar al leer muchos archivos.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes mal es ese `""files[i]/ageb_urb.dbf""`.

Puedes intentar utilizar la función `map_df` del paquete `purrr`

Lo que hace `map_df` es iterar sobre argumentos (**listado de nombres de archivos**) aplicando cierta función (**función para leer un archivo**) y luego reduciendo

```
library(purrr)
library(foreign)

files <- list.files(path ="C:/Users/.../Documents/Datos/Scince/Estados/", 
           full.names = T, recursive = F)

data <- map_df(files, read.dbf)
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta es la respuesta, efectivamente había un error al especificar las rutas. Asimismo si es posible utilizar al mismo tiempo for y lapply de forma anidada.

```
parent <- "C:/Users/.../Documents/Datos/Scince/Estados"

 dirs <- list.dirs(parent, full.names = F, recursive = F)

 require(foreign)

 lapply(dirs, 

    for(i in 1:length(dirs)){

      pob <- read.dbf(paste(parent, dirs[i], "ageb_urb.dbf", sep = "/"))
      edu <- read.dbf(paste(parent, dirs[i], "tablas", "cpv2010_ageb_urb_caracteristicas_educativas.dbf", sep = "/"))
      viv <- read.dbf(paste(parent, dirs[i], "tablas", "cpv2010_ageb_urb_viviendas.dbf", sep = "/"))
  }
```